# Moodle quiz marking guide

Tags: moodle, moodle-theme

I've a requirement where students assignments are to be marked by multiple teachers. Each teacher is allotted certain question numbers. I've created a marking guide with mark entry for each question and pdf annotation is in use.

**Scenario:**

There are 10 questions in the assignment. Question number 1 to 5 is marked by Teacher A and question numbers 6 to 10 is marked by Teacher B.
A marking guide is created to help teacher to enter mark for each question

**The problem:**

To avoid conflict, teachers were given different time frames.
When Teacher A marks his part and leave his colleague's part empty, the entries are not saved. So I tell them to enter 0.
This means second teacher has to over ride 0.

**Looking for:**

Allotting question numbers to teachers so that they can mark only their questions.
If the above is not possible at least they should be able to leave blank (text box for mark entry) to not to touch other part.
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I am also having the same issue...I think if we can default mark field as zero we can overcome this problem